# Dynamic html table on JS without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

How to do dynamic html table on JS? How to do better (appendChild or innerHTML) and **not** use jQuery. For example I must have 6 buttons:

- Add row to begin table;
- Add row to middle;
- Add row to end;
- Delete first row;
- Delete middle row;
- Delete last row;

Comment: Why makes you not using jQuery?

Comment: jQuery only takes 32kb space, so why not use that. It will save you a lot of time using that... Doing such thing without jQuery is just trying to invent the wheel again.

Comment: Here is a tutorial I found that does some of it using buttons. You should be able to extrapolate from that :) http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddrow.html But I agree to the comments, Why not use jQuery or any other framework.

Comment: For beginning I want clear understand how its working without jQuery, and on next step have compare between 2 ways.

Comment: @GGG, I can't answer on my question, because my reputation lower than 120.

Comment: @Smit oops, I didn't know about that restriction...

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer and remove "resolved" from title. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var table=document.getElementById('table')
    var x;
    for( var j=0; j<list.length; j++){
        x=table.insertRow(-1);
        for(var i=0; i<40; i++)
            x.insertCell(i).innerHTML=list[j][i];
```

This is how i made my dynamic table. after that you can index which row you want to add or delete. This is all done in JS using DOM attributes (i don't really know JQ but im sure you can translate) With this approach you could add a function that finds the middle row of the table. Also if you wanted to make it easier for the user to add rows or remove rows anywhere in the table this method allows that since it will add it dynamically depending on the index you send

```
table.deleteRow(table.rows.length-1);//deletes last row
table.deleteRow(0); //deletes first row
```

To read more about DOM table methods:http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/tablemethods.shtml

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

```
function addRow(val) {
    // Get a reference to the table
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    var tmp = 1;
    if (val == 1) tmp = 1;
    if (val == 2) tmp = lastRow / 2;
    if (val == 3) tmp = lastRow - 1;

    // Insert a row in the table at row index  
    var newRow = tbl.insertRow(tmp);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index 0 1 2 3
    var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
    var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
    var newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);

    // Append a text node to the cell
    var newText = document.createTextNode('New row')
    newCell.appendChild(newText);
}


function removeLast() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 2);
}


function removeFirst() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(1);
}


function removeMiddle() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
    if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow / 2 - 1);
}
```